# Form controls hidden in Libre Office basic macro designer - but shown in testmode

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-basic, libreoffice-basic

I have imported an original VBA form (the design) into Libre Office (Version 4.4.2.2) .
However, some form controls are hidden in the designer mode, but are clearly there in the preview/test mode.

**Does anyone know, how I can edit the "hidden" controls or make them visible again?**
See the two attached screenshots:
In the frame/groupbox Options and in the frame Stored tables, the inside controls are missing.
From what I think, they are kind of hidden under the groupbox/frame. 
I haven't figured a way to bring them back to front.
To import the dialog in Libre Office paste the code into a new .xdl file and import the dialog file into a macro. 
[Dialog *.xdl content](http://pastebin.com/sp4C7esB)

[image: Libre Office Designer view]

[image: Libre Office Preview/Testmode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else struggles with this problem, I just figured it out, why it wasn't displayed, the control was marked as frame and not as titledbox.
Just replace *frame* with *titledbox*.

```
<dlg:frame dlg:style-id="6" dlg:id="frmStorage" dlg:tab-index="6" dlg:left="277" dlg:top="4" dlg:width="149" dlg:height="252">  
...
</dlg:frame>
```

Afterwards reimport the dialog.
Et voila, the hidden fields are also shown in the designer.
[image: Groupbox content shown correct]